# C preprocessor library

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a task of developing source analysis tool for **C** programs, and I need to pre-process code before the analysis itself. I was wondering what is the best library for this. I need something light-weight and portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of rolling out your own, why not use `cpp` that's part of the `gcc` suite: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/cpp/

```
CPP(1)                                GNU                               CPP(1)

NAME
       cpp - The C Preprocessor

SYNOPSIS
       cpp [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
           [-Idir...] [-iquotedir...]
           [-Wwarn...]
           [-M|-MM] [-MG] [-MF filename]
           [-MP] [-MQ target...]
           [-MT target...]
           [-P] [-fno-working-directory]
           [-x language] [-std=standard]
           infile outfile

       Only the most useful options are listed here; see below for the
       remainder.

DESCRIPTION
       The C preprocessor, often known as cpp, is a macro processor that is
       used automatically by the C compiler to transform your program before
       compilation.  It is called a macro processor because it allows you to
       define macros, which are brief abbreviations for longer constructs.
```

Comment: This was also my basic idea, but i was wondering if there was any way to do it, without using `cpp`.

Comment: I guess I'm left wondering why you would *need* to do it without using `cpp`.  Ie - there exists a mature solution for the problem you posed.  What is it about that solution that is insufficient to the task?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to do it, other than `cpp`, maybe something more efficient. Anyway, i will probably use `cpp`, because of its portability.

Comment: @Kijan what part of your cpp did you find inefficient?

Comment: Regardless of efficiency, using a C preprocessor as a library from inside another application is a legitimate use-case. Let's say I get a C file as a buffer and I want to preprocess it. Writing it to a file and calling a command-line tool on it is way overkill.